# Segmentation fault in dynamic linker(rv64ima-lp64) while debugging

Tags: linux, gdb, glibc, dynamic-linking, riscv

I am using latest riscv-gnu-toolchain to build the filesystem and the binary. The gdb and gdbserver are working perfectly for rv64imafd-lp64d. But I am working on rv64ima-lp64 and trying to debug.

1. ./riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc -v

```
COLLECT_GCC=./riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu-gcc
COLLECT_LTO_WRAPPER=/home/qc/ools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-linux-ima/libexec/gcc/riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu/10.2.0/lto-wrapper
Target: riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu
Configured with: /home/qc/tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-linux-ima/./../riscv-gcc/configure --target=riscv64-unknown-linux-gnu --prefix=/home/qc/tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-linux-ima --with-sysroot=/home/qc/tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-linux-ima/sysroot --with-system-zlib --enable-shared --enable-tls --enable-languages=c,c++,fortran --disable-libmudflap --disable-libssp --disable-libquadmath --disable-libsanitizer --disable-nls --disable-bootstrap --src=.././../riscv-gcc --disable-multilib --with-abi=lp64 --with-arch=rv64ima --with-tune=rocket 'CFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -mcmodel=medlow' 'CXXFLAGS_FOR_TARGET=-O2 -mcmodel=medlow'
Thread model: posix
Supported LTO compression algorithms: zlib
gcc version 10.2.0 (GCC)
```

2. While debugging a simple helloworld program using gdbserver, I got this error

```
    Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
    0x0000003ff7fed850 in _dl_debug_initialize (ldbase=18446744073709551615, ns=0) at dl-debug.c:49
    49 if (ns == LM_ID_BASE)
    (gdb) bt
    #0 0x0000003ff7fed850 in _dl_debug_initialize (ldbase=18446744073709551615, ns=0) at dl-debug.c:49
    #1 0x0000003ff7fed984 in _dl_debug_vdprintf (fd=<optimized out>, tag_p=-134225776, fmt=0xffffffffffffffff <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff>, arg=0x800011e17) at dl-misc.c:120
    #2 0x0000003ff7ec76cc in ?? ()
    (gdb) info stack
    #0 0x0000003ff7fed850 in _dl_debug_initialize (ldbase=18446744073709551615, ns=0) at dl-debug.c:49
    #1 0x0000003ff7fed984 in _dl_debug_vdprintf (fd=<optimized out>, tag_p=-134225776, fmt=0xffffffffffffffff <error: Cannot access memory at address 0xffffffffffffffff>, arg=0x800011e17) at dl-misc.c:120
    #2 0x0000003ff7ec76cc in ?? ()
```

3. The program executes successfully while without using any debugger.
4. I also tried debugging it remotely as well as natively on the target. The error remains the same i.e.
   Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
   0x0000003ff7fed310 in ?? () from /lib/ld-linux-riscv64-lp64.so.1
5. Therefore the issue might not be in the gdbserver.
6. Also, another time I was debugging it remotely, there was slight variation in the error

```
(gdb) l
1    <built-in>: No such file or directory.
(gdb) c
Continuing.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
_dl_debug_initialize (ldbase=0, ns=1685382482) at dl-debug.c:54
54      if (r->r_map == NULL || ldbase != 0)
(gdb) bt
#0  _dl_debug_initialize (ldbase=0, ns=1685382482) at dl-debug.c:54
#1  0x0000003ff7fe2dc4 in dl_main (phdr=<optimized out>, phnum=<optimized out>, user_entry=<optimized out>, auxv=<optimized out>) at rtld.c:1596
#2  0x0000003ff7ff3ea8 in _dl_sysdep_start (start_argptr=start_argptr@entry=0x3ffffffdc0, dl_main=dl_main@entry=0x3ff7fe1cb0 <dl_main>) at ../elf/dl-sysdep.c:253
#3  0x0000003ff7fe185c in _dl_start_final (arg=0x3ffffffdc0) at rtld.c:415
#4  _dl_start (arg=0x3ffffffdc0) at rtld.c:522
#5  0x0000003ff7fe0ee8 in _start () from /home/qc/anaadi/archives/tools/riscv-gnu-toolchain/build-linux-ima/sysroot/lib/ld-linux-riscv64-lp64.so.1
Backtrace stopped: frame did not save the PC
(gdb) info r
ra             0x3ff7fe2dc4    0x3ff7fe2dc4 <dl_main+4372>
sp             0x3ffffffad0    0x3ffffffad0
gp             0x140100    0x140100
tp             0x3ff7dbc720    0x3ff7dbc720
t0             0x3    3
t1             0x3ff7fe0e7c    274743561852
t2             0x6ffffeff    1879047935
fp             0x3ffffffcf0    0x3ffffffcf0
s1             0x0    0
a0             0x7879c0df18    517438758680
a1             0x6474e552    1685382482
a2             0x6474e552    1685382482
a3             0x3ff7fe0158    274743558488
a4             0x0    0
a5             0x3881c0fe20    242695077408
a6             0x1    1
a7             0x3ff7fffc58    274743688280
s2             0x3ff7ffd8c8    274743679176
s3             0x1    1
s4             0x10    16
s5             0x3ff7fff008    274743685128
s6             0x0    0
s7             0x10000    65536
s8             0x2e    46
s9             0x3ff7ffd908    274743679240
s10            0x3ff7fff160    274743685472
s11            0x3ff7fff090    274743685264
t3             0x3ff7ff43c4    274743641028
t4             0x4    4
t5             0x4    4
t6             0x4    4
pc             0x3ff7fedabc    0x3ff7fedabc <_dl_debug_initialize+40>
```

What can be done for this? Or is there any work around this ?

Let me know if additional information is needed to analyse the issue.

[As asked, the glibc version is 2.29 and the github url for the same is https://github.com/riscv/riscv-glibc ]